# Automorphism Group of central products

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, automorphism-group

Let $D_{2^n}$ be a dihedal group of order $2^n$ and $Q_{2^n}$ be a quaternion group of order $2^n.$

I am looking for a reference about the structure of $Aut(D_{2^n}*C_{2^k})$ and $Aut(Q_{2^n}*C_{2^k})$ where $*$ is a central product and $C_{2^k}$ is a cyclic group of order $2^k$.

For example, I obtained that $Aut(D_{2^n}*C_{2^k})$ is a 2-group when $n\geq 4$ with a long calculation (if correct). But I think there should be  a reference for that.

Any comment and well known fact about it is welcome.

Comment: Just a quick notational note: $*$ usually reads as the free product; I've seen $\circ$ used for central products.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: People working on finite groups may use "*" although people working on general groups do not like it.

Comment: Do note the "usually". In fact, the source for $\circ$ I've seen is Leedham-Green and McKay's *Structure of groups of prime power order*, a quintessentially "finite group" text.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: If you check the book, It has sections named Pro-finite groups, free groups,.... Thus, it makes sense not to use * in this book.